# Single Word for "with the risk of"

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine the situation where an astronaut is to leave Earth and possibly never return.

> He continued his journey, `with the risk of` never returning to his family.

How would you substitute "with the risk of" in one word? I know "despite" could be used, but is not the word I look for.

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with *risking*? Or *chancing*?

Comment: If you must have only one word, "hazarding" might be best, although I don't like the "ing ... ing" much.

Answer (score 1):

"He continued his journey, [potentially](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/potentially) never returning to his family"

Potentially

> possibly but not yet actually:

[Possibly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/possibly) works too:

> perhaps; maybe

References:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/potentially
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/possibly

Answer (score 0):

> He continued his journey **risking** never to return to his family.